# Skimming with full resources

Tags: cuba-libre

In our yesterday's *Cuba Libre* game, the Government was doing excellent with their resources and hit the maximum of 49 resources before receiving the Skim of all Syndicate casinos. In this case, what happens? Does the Syndicate still lose 2 resources for every Government-controlled space with open casinos, or do they get to keep the resources since the Government cannot receive them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Rule 6.2.3. [...] any over 49 are lost [...]

So the Syndicate loses those resources but they are lost and no one receives them.

Maybe the Government henchmen kept the skim for them.